# Removing an image and showing this removed image in the deleted section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one `div` **"upload"** where various `images` are displayed and each image has an **remove** option which if clicked on hides the image.

I need to show the particular hidden images in below deleted section.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="upload"> 
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick= remove()>  Remove  </a>
         <img src="pic1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="deleted">
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
  function remove(){
      $("upload").hide();
  }
```

If I `click` on `remove` option in `div` "upload" then I need to `hide` that `image` and simultaneously `show` that `image` in `div` "deleted".

Comment: where is  `remove()` function ?

Comment: i have added that...for now it just hide the div part

Answer (score 1):

I've done some changes your original code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="upload">
    <a>Remove</a> <img src="pic1.jpg" />
    <a>Remove</a> <img src="pic2.jpg" />
    <!-- etc. -->
</div>

<div id="deleted"></div>
```

**JS** (with jQuery)

```
$(function() {
    $("#upload a").click(function(e) {
        $(this).next("img").appendTo($("#deleted"));
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

By using jQuery, you can dynamically bind the `click` event to every `a` inside `#upload`. Then, relatively to the clicked `a`, find the next `img`, append it to `#deleted` (with `appendTo`), and finally delete the clicked `a`.

Answer (score 0):

follow the below steps

```
<div id="upload"> 
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id ="removebutton">  Remove  </a>
    <img src="pic1.png"/>
</div>

<div id="deleted">
</div>
```

Javascript part

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#removebutton").click(function() {  
   $("#deleted").html($("#upload").find("img"));
});
});
```

Check this working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zzpgn6zr/

Let me know if it is helpful

Comment: Actually I cant make changes to my code  because there are many other things also happening in remove javascript function....

Comment: Then share it here using jsfiddle

Comment: No use to share the js function because other things(for eg-> one ajax request to remove image details from db) are independent of this hide() function

Comment: Ok no need to change your code. I just now edited my answer above. check the HTML part as yours. just added `id="removebutton"`

The same javascript functino will work as you expected

Comment: Please let me know whether this answer is helpful or not and check the fiddle in my above comment

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a sample JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x3f6L9re/ with a demonstration how the problem can be solved.

Since you're intending to use jQuery, please don't add the function call in the HTML.

This line:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick= remove()>  Remove  </a>
```

is thus obsolete. I used the tag `button` instead of `a`, which fits better here.

My code would be:

HTML

```
<div id="upload">
    <figure>
        <button type="button" role="button">Remove</button>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9e/JQuery_logo.svg/524px-JQuery_logo.svg.png" alt="Image">
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <button type="button" role="button">Remove</button>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Crystal_source.png" alt="Image">
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <button type="button" role="button">Remove</button>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ca/AngularJS_logo.svg/695px-AngularJS_logo.svg.png" alt="Image">
    </figure>
</div>

<div id="deleted">
</div>
```

I enclosed every image in a tag `figure` for better demarcation.

CSS

```
#upload, #deleted, figure {
    border: thin solid black;
}
```

Adding border for visualisation of the effects.

And here is the jQuery:

JavaScript

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('#deleted').append($(this).next());
    $(this).next().hide();
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent().css('border', 'none');
});
```

When a button is clicked its next sibling, which is the image, is appended to the `div` with `id="deleted"`. Then the next sibling of the button, the image, is hidden, together with the button itself. For cosmetical purposes the border of the parent element - `figure` - is removed.

You can further enhance the code.